# ExtJS: How do I get raw JSON data from Ext.data.Store?

Tags: extjs4

From a typical store like this

```
Ext.define('User', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        {name: 'firstName', type: 'string'},
        {name: 'lastName',  type: 'string'},
        {name: 'age',       type: 'int'},
        {name: 'eyeColor',  type: 'string'}
    ]
});

var myStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'User',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url : '/users.json',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'users'
        }
    },
    autoLoad: true
});
```

Is it possible to get raw Json from myStore?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What about:

```
myStore.proxy.reader.rawData
```

Comment: @Tenerezza So what's the difference? Of course we are able to access the data only after the data is loaded into the store...

Comment: The difference is that you need to go by store.getProxy().getReader().rawData to access the data.

Answer (score 12):

The accepted solution did not work in my configuration: ExtJs 4.1 and a grid with a memory proxy - it returned empty after I added items to the gird (and the store object reflected that). The following code worked for encoding store contents into a JSON string:

```
var json = Ext.encode(Ext.pluck(store.data.items, 'data'));
```

Cheers!

Comment: While this solution works, it relies on the private data property and as such is not guaranteed to work in future releases of ExtJs.  It's unfortunate that ExtJs does not have a supported way of doing this.

Comment: 6.5.x: Ext.encode(Ext.Array.pluck(store.data.items, 'data'));

Answer (score 4):

Took me ages to find a solution to this but here is one solution that will work.

```
    myStore .on({ 'load': function (store, records, successful)
    {
        console.log(store.getProxy().getReader().rawData);
    } 
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The proxy reader rawData/jsonData will become accessible after the store is created.  To access it try the following:

```
store.on('load', function() {
  console.log('store.proxy.reader.jsonData');
  console.log(store.proxy.reader.jsonData);
}, this, { single: true });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Ext.data.Store({....
            proxy: {
                       ...
                       reader: {
                       **keepRawData: true,**
                       type: 'json',
                       rootProperty: 'root',
                       successProperty: 'success'
                       }
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score -1):

Look like I found the solution by hooking event listeners to data store:

```
var myStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
  ...
  listeners: {
    'load': {
      fn: function(store, records, success, operations) {
        Ext.each(records, function(rec) {
          console.log(Ext.encode(rec.raw));
        });
      }
    }
  }
  ...
});
```

Comment: This only get the data from the root json node but not the rest of it.

Answer (score -1):

maybe, you can try with this:

```
var json = Ext.JSON.encode(myStore.getRange());
```

cya!

Comment: That'll give you a "maximum call stack size exceeded" error.